# Integrating over this region?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the volume of the region bounded by $z=4-x^2, x+y=2$, and the coordinate planes.

I know I use and triple integral, and integrate one, but I can't figure out the limits on $y$. I know that $0\leq z \leq 4-x^2$, and $0 \leq x \leq 2$, but what y's limits?

Comment: Have you tried to sketch this region?

Comment: Standard way to find the bounds of integration for a triple integral: Sketch first, then use either [this method](http://mathinsight.org/triple_integral_shadow_method) or [this method](http://mathinsight.org/triple_integral_cross_section_method), depending on which seems easier (usually, the second one).